# BJT VEB ratings availability

Tags: transistors

All Silicon transistors appear to have a reverse base  emitter breakdown voltage rating of no more than about 8 VDC  .It would be extremely useful to have a much higher volt rating . Some OLD germanium transistors are a bit better like say 12V           but probably not worth the hassle.WHY don't they make SI transistors with a higher VEB ?

Comment: Probably because there are other ways of solving the problem. What problem are you trying to solve with high reverse breakdown anyway?

Comment: A high reverse breakbown would allow synchronous rectification at high volts where mosfets get expensive as current goes up.

Comment: No it wouldn't. Unless there is a suitable LV supply available, the power from base drive for a bipolar synchronous rectifier would be  greater than the sync. rectifier saves.
High BVEBO has no influence on a the suitability of a device for this function.

Answer (score 1):

It's 'Silicon', not 'Silicone'

Most transistors are constructed to have high beta and low emitter resistance. This leads to doping the emitter as heavily as is practical, and this in turn leads to a B-E junction with a maximum voltage capability of around 5 V. Note that sometimes the BV is higher than this, but in some devices, sustained bias at E-B voltages over 5 V will cause severe degradation in the device characteristics.

Comment: jp314  you genius ! what I can infer from your valid answer is that if such a device was made then it would have crappy gain ? If I could live with a gain of less than one then is such a device theoraticly possible ?

Comment: Synch rectifier just to make things easy for others to understand .Not the target app.

Comment: Sure they are possible. In Integrated circuits when PNPs are available, they generally have BVCEO = BVEBO, and this can be as high as 40 V. Those device are not generally available individually (and would be very expensive). I think there were some discrete PNPs available with high BVEBO, but I can't find them online now.

Comment: Sure -- if you don't want high gain, choose a low BVCEO device, and operate in reverse ! You will get high 'BVEBO', but low 'BVCEO' (with emitter & collector swapped). A low (forward) BVCEO device will have higher reverse gain than a high voltage  device.

Comment: So I could use a HVBJT as a diode in CB mode and use the emitter as the collector and not worry about less than unity gain and make sure Ib is not exceeded.

Comment: Certainly; its better to connect E&B together -- if reverse beta is > 0, at least some of the total current will flow in the emitter, and performance will be somewhat better.

Comment: If I could just use CB then the emmiter can be used for sensing .Thank you for warning me that the CB diode will be inferior.I am still tempted to do this because my scheme does not have the reverse recovery stress on the diode .